# Generic overloading tells me this is the same function. Not agree

Tags: .net, generics, oop, overriding

base class:

```
Class List(Of T)
    Function Contains(ByVal value As T) As Boolean
```

derived class:

```
Class Bar : List(Of Exception) ' Exception type as example '
    Function Contains(Of U)(ByVal value As U) As Boolean
```

compiler tells me that that two are the same, so I need to declare Overloads/new this second function.

But I want use U to differentiate the type (one logic) like NullReferenceException, ArgumentNull Exception, etc. but want to leave the base function(no differentiation by type - other logic) as well.

Comment: Arrrrg, my eyes! The vb generics are burning my eyes!

Answer (score 4):

Well the equivalent certainly compiles in C#. I'd say you should avoid doing it, however - give your method a different name if it's going to behave differently. Overloading by type parameter in a derived class is rarely a good idea - and indeed deriving from `List<T>` is rarely a good idea in itself.

In VB you have to declare that you're explicitly overloading - which you are. You should add `Overloads` to the function declaration. Basically this method is *not* the same as the base `Contains` method - it has a different number of type parameters (1 instead of 0) and the parameter is of a different type (`U` instead of `T`). Note that contrary to your title you're *not* overriding anything.

Can you give more indication about what you're actually trying to achieve with this class? We may be able to suggest a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to pass a different type to the class then you might want to use a where in your generic declaration.  That might be enough info for the compiler to be happy.